# How to make common static conetnt(js,css) available to all jsps in Struts1 application

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts1

Is there any way we can include the common *static content(like js,css etc files)* in all JSPs of project, without touching each one of them. (I have large number of JSPs and I am using **STRUTS 1**).
In know include and tags but they will cause us to insert in each of the JSPs.
I know we have this feature in STRUTS 2 ( using struts.serve.static property of struts.properties file)

So is there any other way we can do it in STRUTS1?

**Edit** : I am using tiles-def for now. And it works fine. But it still needs changes at more than one places.

Comment: If you're not using any sort of templating system, of course not--there's no magic injection of things. But if you're using Tiles you should have a top-level-ish tile definition into which you can put it.

Comment: Yes. Thats what I am doing right now. But I feel there should  be something where we neednt't create a new top-level tile just fr the sake of adding the content.  STRUTS2 have it..

Comment: If you organized your tiles in such a way you can't include content on every page then I'd suggest you organized your tiles poorly. Even basic jsp templating allows injection of arbitrary content if you've planned accordingly. There are any number of ways you could subvert the system and inject content-then you'd have a different kind of mess. Not sure what you're talking about with S2; it uses the same basic view mechanisms as S1.